# Issues with Proguard

Tags: proguard, codenameone

Can't write [/tmp/build6309103814222260819xxx/Application/build/intermediates/transforms/proguard/release/jars/3/1f/main.jar] (Can't read [/tmp/build6309103814222260819xxx/Application/libs/json-path-2.4.0-all.jar(;;;;;;**/*.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [org/c/a.class == json-path-2.4.0-all.jar:org/json/JSONArray.class]))

Comment: simply removed org.json package